# Contact database with reminders and notes

Tags: ios, information-management, crm, contact-manager

Purpose: I'm looking to keep up-to-date knowledge about my contacts, but only through self written details.

I can only find smarter apps connecting to LinkedIn, Facebook, etc - I feel these distract from the simple features I'm looking for.

Features (in order of desirability, first being most important)

1. I can write down lots of details about contacts. Notes which are more transient like "Currently thinking about changing jobs", notes which are a bit of a wiki on that person such as "Favourite movie is The Shining", and notes about what we did when we last met/spoke "Met for coffee and chatted about Canada trip"
2. I can schedule reminders for important dates (such as hospital appointment or wishing well for a vacation)
3. I can write down when I last saw someone, and it gives me an overview of my contacts based on how long ago I've seen them

Any recommendations on mobile (iOS) apps (with possible Mac or Windows accompaniment) or systems that may appear more optimal are much appreciated. I'd buy an app if it had a one-off fee but I'm not looking for paid services.

Comment: Have no idea of an app like this for iOS, but in android, you have this app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lickilicky.app.android.contacts&hl=en

This lets you take notes, add tasks and reminders.

DEV is working on developing iOS app too. You can expect it soon. Meanwhile you can try it if you have android phone :)